# JQuery number re-sequencing children that contain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to re-sequence some number labels but I only want it to loop through the selectors that contain children that have a specific class.

My html:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
   <span class="add-on">1</span>
   <input data-line-id="4613" type="text" class="input-large address-line" value="6 Flakefield">
   <img data-toggle="tooltip" class="input-action delete-line" src="/public_html/images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" data-original-title="Delete line 1.">
</div>
```

And JQuery:

```
$('#addressStepContent').on('click', '.delete-line', function(){
   //$(this).parent().detach();
   $.each($(this).parent().siblings('> .address-line').andSelf(), function(i, v){
       $(this).children('.add-on').text(i+1)
   })
})
```

Which doesn't work, it only effects the `input-prepend` div you clicked the delete image on.

How do I get this to loop through the selectors that contain a child with class `.address-line`

---

It also needs to stop or break out of the loop when it encounters a label element.

Comment: i can't see `addressStepContent DOM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. If you have any ideas on how to make it better please do tell:

```
$('#addressStepContent').on('click', '.delete-line', function(){
      targets = $(this).parent().siblings();

      $(this).parent().detach();
      n = 0
      $.each(targets, function(i, v){
        if($(this).is('label') && $(this).text() != 'Address lines')
        {
          alert($(this).text())
          return false;
        } else {
          if($(this).children('.add-on').length > 0)
          {
            n++;
          }
          $('.add-on', this).text(n);
        }
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

use find..and i think you don't need loop there

tyr this..

```
 $(this).parent().find('.add-on').text(i+1)
```

or

```
$(this).siblings('.add-on').text(i+1)
```

or

```
$(this).closest('.add-on').text(i+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried like this??

```
 $.each($(this).parent().find('.address-line'), function(i, v){
        $(this).children('.add-on').text(i+1)
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$('#addressStepContent').on('click', '.delete-line', function(){
    var i = $(this).closest('div').index();
    $(this).siblings('.add-on').text(i+1);
});
```

For this you need a local variable.

`.each()` is not required at all and `.siblings()` seems a bit incorrect. Give this a try and see if it helps.

#### [Chekout the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8ues/)

Comment: This just sets all of them 0 except for the one you click on :(.

Comment: It needs to renumber each one in case I deleted line 3 out of 5 for instance.